# Catching exception caused by network error during Facebook photo upload

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, error-handling, facebook-c#-sdk

I have done photo uploading to Facebook event page, mostly by following this [tutorial](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Upload-Progress.aspx). The result is satisfactory so far, with photos being uploaded to the event page most of the time. However, sometimes when the program is uploading the photo, and the network connection is laggy or severed, the program would crash and throw the `System.AggregateException`, with message:

`A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.`

Through initial inspection, the InnerException of this is:

`[Facebook.WebExceptionWrapper]: {"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."}`

,and the InnerException of the above exception is `System.IO.IOException`, and another `System.Net.Socket.SocketException` inside the IOException, in which, both error messages describe something like `{"An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"}`.

The StackTrace of the exceptions gives me only:

```
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()
```

Now obviously, the problem is caused by crappy network connection the system may encounter sometimes. So, how or where do I handle this exception based on the code referenced from this [tutorial](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Upload-Progress.aspx)? I have no idea where I should put the try-catch block at when this happened in another thread, or so it seems like to me.

Thanks in advanced!

Referenced code from the [tutorial](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Upload-Progress.aspx):

```
var mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject
                              {
                                  ContentType = "image/jpeg",
                                  FileName = Path.GetFileName(_filename)
                              }
                              .SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(_filename));

var fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);
fb.PostCompleted += fb_PostCompleted;
fb.PostAsync("/me/photos", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "source", mediaObject } });

public void fb_PostCompleted(object sender, FacebookApiEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Cancelled)
  {
    var cancellationError = e.Error;
    MessageBox.Show("Upload cancelled");
  }
  else if (e.Error == null)
  {
    // upload successful.
    MessageBox.Show(e.GetResultData().ToString());
  }
  else
  {
    // upload failed
    MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does wrapping it in a `try..catch` not work? You can catch the `AggregateException` and inspect its content for the inner exception causing the issue.

Comment: I wrapped the whole block with try-catch from FacebookClient instance creation to the PostAsync statements. I tried disconnect my internet connection in the middle of my upload. The program still crashes! The exception info I got is what the debugger shows when the program crashes while debugging.